# UnexpectedToken error when I try to use return with ternary operator but not with if statement?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, return, conditional-operator

so I noticed something very strange. When I try to exit a function with `return` keyword in the if statement it works well but when I try to do this with the ternary operator it throws `UnexpectedToken` error (expected expression, got keyword 'return'). Why does this happen?

My code:

```
function monthName(nr) {
    0 < nr < 13 ? alert("Month: " + months[nr]) : return false;
  }

monthName(mnr);
```

But with if statement:

```
function monthName(nr) {
  if (0 < nr < 13)
    alert("Month: " + months[nr]);
  else
    return false;
  }

monthName(mnr);
```

It works fine. So why can't I use `return` keyword with ternary operator but with if statement it works?

Comment: `0 < nr < 13` is `(0 < nr) < 13` which is `(true < 13)` or `(false <13)`

Comment: <pedantry>`? :` is called the *conditional* operator. It's **a** ternary operator (an operator accepting three operands, just like a binary operator accepts two and a unary operator accepts one), and it's currently JavaScript's only ternary operator, but that could change. ;-) </pedantry>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why does this happen?

Because `return` is a *statement*, and you can't put statements where only expressions are allowed.¹  The conditional operator's operands must be expressions, not statements. (You'd have the same problem with `throw`, just FWIW, though there's talk of adding a `throw` operator... Or with `while` or `for` or any other statement.)

The `if` is probably your best bet.

**If** you were really, really intent on just using a single expression, you could put the `return` at the start so the single expression is what follows it:

```
function monthName(nr) {
    return 0 < nr < 13 ? alert("Month: " + months[nr]) : false;
}
```

Note that that relies on the fact that `alert` returns `undefined` in order to maintain the two return values you were providing in your `if` example (`undefined` if the `alert` was shown, `false` if not). Interestingly, [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-alert) doesn't explicitly say that `alert` returns `undefined` but I think we can safely accept that it's implicitly specified (not least because the implicit return of any non-arrow JavaScript function is `undefined` unless `return <value>` is used).

---

¹ *(You **can** do the opposite; JavaScript has the concept of the "expression statement" which means any expression is also a valid statement.)*

Answer (score 1):

You can only include expressions in ternaries. If you look at the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), you'll notice that there are only string, bools, etc after the condition. The closest solution only returns or only alerts:

```
function monthName(nr) {
  return 0 < nr < 13 ? "Month: " + months[nr] : false;
}
```

or

```
function monthName(nr) {
  alert(0 < nr < 13 ? "Month: " + months[nr] : false);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In a ternary the `return` cannot be an operand. Therefore when the interpreter reads the `:` operator in the ternary expression it expects a valid value to follow but instead sees the reserved keywork `return` causing the program to throw and error.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, this is not like in math, you can not do

```
0 < nr < 13
```

because this will try to do the first comparison `0 < nr` and then the result of this, it will be compared to `13`

so basically if `nr` is positive, it will always be true

```
0 < nr // true
```

therefore

```
true < 13 // true
```

you can check this in the following code:

```js
console.log(0 < 5 < 13, " -> should be true! good")
console.log(0 < 5000 < 13, " -> should be false! but it is true")
```

so in order to do the things correct, you need to concatenate the expressions using `AND`

```
(0 < nr) && (nr < 13)
```

now, to the things you asked, basically as the other responses say, you are trying to use an `statement` where you can only use `expressions`, if you read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator), it says you need to provide an `expression to execute`.

so, to fix your issue, you can return the whole ternary expression.

```js
function monthName(nr) {
  return (0 < nr) && (nr < 13) ? alert("Month: " + nr) : false;
}

monthName(5);
```

or if you want a shorthand:

```
const monthName = nr => (0 < nr) && (nr < 13) ? alert("Month: " + nr) : false;

monthName(5);
```